# Are $(\exists x)(\forall y)3x^2y-xy+5y=7$ and $(\forall y)(\exists x)3x^2y-xy+5y=7$ true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the statements

$(\exists x)(\forall y)3x^2y-xy+5y=7$

and

$(\forall y)(\exists x)3x^2y-xy+5y=7$

I'm asked to answer if the two statements are true or false for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

For the first statement, I would say false, since for any $x$ we choose, then we'll have a "$..+5y=7$" which won't be true for any $y$ we pick.
For the second statement, I would say false, since $y=0$ makes the statement false.

I'm then asked to answer if the two statements are true or false for $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$, however I don't see how that changes anything, by using the same argumentation as above?

Comment: Note that your question and the title don't match. Please fix it.

Comment: For the first statement, to show it is false, one has to (here explicitly) find a value for $y=y_x$ and mention it, so that the corresponding equality fails. Simply mention the same choice, $y=y_x=0$. The argument works over any field with $7\ne0$, so $\Bbb C$ is the same game.

Answer (score 1):

All are false. Consider $y=0$.